# HomeKit issues when using HMCatalog app

Tags: ios, iot, homekit, ios-homekit

I'm currently working on a mobile app for a HomeKit compliant accessory. I am using the HMCatalog app and the HomeKit Accessory Simulator for testing purposes.

The issue I'm seeing involves my mobile app and the HMCatalog app. I was under the impression that HomeKit syncs through a user's iCloud account. When I am signed in with my iCloud account on one phone (Phone A), any Homes/Rooms/Accessories that I add on in the Catalog on Phone A will show up in my mobile app on Phone A.

However, when I use Phone B, and sign into the same iCloud account, I don't see the same data in Phone B that was in Phone A. The information appearing in HM Catalog appears it is staying on the individual device and not being stored in iCloud.

Has anyone else seen this? Is this an issue with HomeKit? With the Catalog app?

Answer (score 1):

I found that with HomeKit there are some propagation issues. Sometimes it depends on the network you are in (some block _hap services).

Best way to test it is with a local USB dongle and put the accessories in the dongle network. This should limit the propagation issues.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was pulling my hair on this one. It's an iOS issue, and after a lot of agonizing hours, this worked for me:

1. Ensure the device has iOS version > 8.1
2. Log out and log back in iCloud.

See the following thread. It should be fixed in iOS > 8.1 however, may appear intermittently.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/1054540#1054540